# Cannot dereference value-initialized deque iterator

Tags: c++, deque

I have one thread filling the deque with push back calls. That thread first locks the mutex and then it is doing its thing.

The second thread is taking deque pointer of the original deque and just read it and I am getting the error "cannot dereference value-initialized deque iterator" while reading the deque. I have checked and I am not going outside the bounds of the deque.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
// Thread 1
deque<float> main_deque;

void FillDeque()
{
    MutexLock Lock(mutex);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < main_deque.size(); i++)
    {
        main_deque.push_back(-10.0);
    }
}

// Thread 2

void ReadDeque(deque<float> *main_deque)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < main_deque->size(); i++)
    {
        float a = (*main_deque)[i];
    }
}
```

EDIT: If I change deque to vector everything works correctly.

Comment: `ReadDeque` does not use mutex for synchronization.

Comment: Thanks, but does it need it? Vectors work great with the same implementation.

Comment: Unsynchronized access to variable is always an undefined behavior. vector does not work either (even if you are not getting an error).

Comment: Does it need synchronization?  Yes!  They both do.  Vectors are usually implemented as an array, maintaining contiguous memory.  Of course, as they grown, they have to be recopied into a new location.  dequeues add better front insertion capabilities but do not promise to keep the memory contiguous.  So, you are less likely to run into a synchronization problem with the vector than the dequeue.  If you write a good test, I suspect that you will have problems with the vector as well, you just have not hit it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. What do you suggest I need to do? Lock mutex for ReadDeque too?